# Calculate all differences between adjacent columns

Tags: awk, sed

I have data like this in a file as shown below

```
60.5(r) 426.5(f) 810.5(r) 1176.5(f) 1560.5(r) 1926.5(f) 2310.5(r) 2676.5(f) 3060.5(r) 3426.5(f) 3810.5(r) 4176.5(f) 4560.5(r) 4926.5(f) 5310.5(r) 5676.5(f) 6060.5(r) 6426.5(f) 6810.5(r) 7176.5(f) 7560.5(r) 7926.5(f) 8310.5(r)
```

Every thing is in the same line and i want to compute the difference of [2nd column - 1st column] [3rd column - 2nd column] for all the columns and copy in another file (in differnt lines)

My tries:

```
awk '{for (i=3;i < NF;i++) print $i}' > file.txt
```

But i don't know how to delete `(r)`, `(f)` and do the difference simultaneously and copy in other file

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo '60.5(r) 426.5(f) 810.5(r) 1176.5(f) 1560.5(r) 1926.5(f) 2310.5(r) 2676.5(f) 3060.5(r) 3426.5(f) 3810.5(r) 4176.5(f) 4560.5(r) 4926.5(f) 5310.5(r) 5676.5(f) 6060.5(r) 6426.5(f) 6810.5(r) 7176.5(f) 7560.5(r) 7926.5(f) 8310.5(r)' \
| awk -F'[()fr]+' '
    {for (i = 2; i < NF; i++) { 
        printf("%d ", $i - $(i-1))
    } print ""}'
366 384 366 384 366 384 366 384 366 384 366 384 366 384 366 384 366 384 366 384 366 384
```

**revised** based on [sudo_O's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23136543/918938) answer:

```
$ echo '60.5(r) 426.5(f) 810.5(r) 1176.5(f) 1560.5(r) 1926.5(f) 2310.5(r) 2676.5(f) 3060.5(r) 3426.5(f) 3810.5(r) 4176.5(f) 4560.5(r) 4926.5(f) 5310.5(r) 5676.5(f) 6060.5(r) 6426.5(f) 6810.5(r) 7176.5(f) 7560.5(r) 7926.5(f) 8310.5(r)' \
| awk -v RS='[()fr]+' -v ORS=' ' '
    1 < NR && NF {print $i - x} 
    {x = $1} 
    END {print "\n"}'
366 384 366 384 366 384 366 384 366 384 366 384 366 384 366 384 366 384 366 384 366 384
```

**revised** based on [JS웃's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/970195/js) answer

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS=FS;ORS=" "}
    1 < NR && NF {print $i - x} 
    {x = $1} 
    END {print "\n"}'
366 384 366 384 366 384 366 384 366 384 366 384 366 384 366 384 366 384 366 384 366 384
```

Answer (score 1):

Print the differences between consecutive columns and output one per line:

```
$ awk 'NR>1&&NF{print $1-x}{x=$1}' RS='[(][rf][)]' file
```

Just redirect the output to save to a new file:

```
$ awk 'NR>1&&NF{print $1-x}{x=$1}' RS='[(][rf][)]' file > new_file
```

If you want the differences all on a single line:

```
$ awk 'NR>1&&NF{print $1-x}{x=$1}' RS='[(][rf][)]' file | xargs > new_file
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the difference between 2nd and 1st columns and 3rd and 2nd columns:

```
awk '{gsub("\\([^)]*\\)",""); print $2 - $1, $3 - $2 }' input-file > output-file
```

If you want the difference between all columns:

```
 awk '{gsub("\\([^)]*\\)",""); for(i=2; i<= NF; i++) print $i - $(i-1)}' input > output
```

If you want the output to have the same number of lines as the inupt, try:

```
awk '{gsub("\\([^)]*\\)","");
  for(i=2; i<= NF; i++) printf " %d", $i - $(i-1); print ""}'
```

To get more tabular output, use, `printf "%15d"` or some other format string.

Comment: Thanks for the solution but there are some 30 to 40 columns in the same line .I want the difference between two consecutive columns not jus 2,1 & 3,2

Comment: The question is unclear on several points, the most relevant now being whether you want the output to be in a single line or not.  If you want the output to have the same number of lines as the input, use `printf`.

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need to get rid of `(r)` and `(f)` explicitly. When you perform mathematical operation on fields with characters, they fall off automatically. It is called coercing. Since in your case the non-numeric characters are after the numbers, you can simply do:

```
$ awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) printf "%d%s",$i-$(i-1),(i==NF?RS:FS)}' data
366 384 366 384 366 384 366 384 366 384 366 384 366 384 366 384 366 384 366 384 366 384
```

Comment: +1 I knew about `+0` to coerce a string to numeric, but I didn't realise awk was so perlish about it! I learnt something new today.